# SwiftUI TabView Issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building an app and i'm a fairly beginner in SwiftUI, so this is the problem I have.
I need a landing page which shows first and I've created a view for it you can check it out.

```
     struct LandingView: View {
var body: some View {   
    NavigationView{
    VStack(alignment: .center){
        Image("exxxlogo")
        Spacer()
        Text("Welcome")
            .font(.system(size: 38))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        Text("Click below to continue to the app")
            .font(.system(size: 16))
             .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(.bottom, 35)
        NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()){
            Text("CONTINUE ")
                  .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                  .background(Color.red)
                  .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        
    }
    
        .background(
            
            Image("backgroundlanding")
                
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
               
    )
}
```

And I've also created the views for the tabview to redirect them to so Home,Shop, etc
I've done this to my Contentview

```
    TabView {
        
       
               HomeView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
        
                GamesView()
                    .tabItem{
                        Image(systemName: "gamecontroller")
                        Text("Games")
        
                
                    }
        
        ShopView()
         .tabItem{
             Image(systemName: "bag")
             Text("Shop")
            }
        
        MoreView()
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                Text("More")
        
            }.accentColor(.red)
```

And changed the windowgroup to landingview in the main app.swift file so it pops up first.
But the issue is when you click on the button in landingview, navigationlink redirects you to the homeview but there is no tabviews underneath just blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that your second code example is from `ContentView`. If you want to show the `TabView` that you have in that `ContentView`, then your `NavigationLink` should point to `ContentView`, not `HomeView`.

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
            Text("CONTINUE ")
                  .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                  .background(Color.red)
                  .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed that somehow.